# Prevent showAuthenticationDialog from logging in automatically in a Spotify app

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am using [showAuthenticationDialog and authenticateWithFacebook](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/09321954e7.html) to authenticate with Twitter and Facebook. Once a user logged in with the popup once, it automatically logs them in subsequent times making it impossible to log in with a different account.

Is there a way to clear the cookies in the popup or something similar?

Comment: You should be able to use the logout features in respective API to clear the details. Have you tried FB.logout for example?

Comment: That would work in Facebook's case, but not for Twitter.

Comment: Soundrop's app seems to have this issue too - if I sign in with Twitter, I then can't sign in with a different Twitter account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter's OAuth API has a `force_login` parameter which will force you to enter your login details:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authenticate

Facebook offers a similar `reauthenticate` option:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/

OAuth itself doesn't specify how to do any of this, since it was intended to provide Authorization servers. OpenID Connect specifies a single parameter, 'approval_prompt=force', which will hopefully make this easier in the future.